How to upload Video Assets to Google Ads using API
I am working on automating the upload of video assets to the Google Ads asset library. The process involves first uploading the video to YouTube via the YouTube Data API and then attaching the uploaded video's ID to Google Ads using the Google Ads API.
Here’s a snippet of the code I'm using to upload a video to YouTube:
public void upload(Credential credential) throws Exception {

    YouTube youtubeService = new YouTube.Builder(
        new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
        .setApplicationName("youtube-upload")
        .build();

    File initialFile = new File("src/main/resources/test.mp4");
    InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);

    InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("video/*", targetStream);

    Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();
    VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();
    snippet.setTitle("Test Video " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    snippet.setDescription("A video uploaded via YouTube API");
    snippet.setTags(Arrays.asList("test", "video", "upload"));

    VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
    status.setPrivacyStatus("private");

    videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);
    videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(status);

    YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtubeService.videos()
        .insert(List.of("snippet", "statistics", "status"), videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);

    Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();

    System.out.println("Uploaded video ID: " + returnedVideo.getId());

    adsService.uploadVideo(returnedVideo);
}

The code works as expected and uploads the video to YouTube, retrieves the video ID, and uses it for Google Ads. However, I am hitting YouTube API upload quotas pretty quickly, and this is causing problems for scaling this process.
My Question:
How can I handle or mitigate YouTube API quota limits when uploading videos in bulk?
Is there a way to optimize or reduce the number of quota points consumed when uploading videos via the API?
Are there any alternative approaches or best practices to avoid hitting the quota limit?
Notes:
I am already following YouTube’s best practices for uploads (setting the video privacy to “private,” limiting tags, etc.), but the quota usage is still significant.
The YouTube API quota system allocates 1600 units per day for each project by default. Each video upload request consumes around 1600 units (as per the documentation).
Relevant API Documentation:

YouTube Data API
Google Ads API
Youtube Support Post


YouTube doc says "YouTube Data API have a default quota allocation of 10,000 units per day" for each project.

The question is not very clear to me. What Spring can do in this case? What solution are you expecting here? This is completely depends on the YouTube. If you don't want to bulk upload at a single shot, then make the bulk file upload as a batch process and set a scheduler on that code that uploads it. You can use Spring Batch to achieve this.

I mean creating something like a cron job which will upload file batch wise on a specific time.

Hi @AnishB. I had been in constant touch with Google Ads team and they are convinced that the process should not consume Youtube Credits since we are uploading for Google Ads. Also I need to upload around 500 video files daily and even with a batch job it (which can upload only 5/day) it won't be suffice.

My Question basically asks for help in integration part if there is anything I need to do to make sure that Assets uploaded for Ads should not consume Youtube credits. Since there is only 1 way to upload assets to Google Ads i.e. via Youtube.
